# PHP on the Command Line Scripting using Class OOP and Running with NetBeans

Tags: php, class, netbeans, arguments, command-line-interface

I'm interested to build a **class** using **PHP** language for run it in **NetBeans**.
The class is for run in **Command Line Interface** and I need to pass **Arguments**.

Anybody knows how to use Netbeans for run it?

The implementation based on **OOP** concepts.

Thank you.

Chepe

Comment: not sure i know what running a php class, in NetBeans, actully means.

Comment: As stated [`here`](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/quickstart.html), you can't simply run php in netbeans. For your task you need to install a local interpreter for your task, in addition the official [`documentation`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) might be interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run the class, but you can create a little "test.php" that will initialize your class and run it.

You can do few things:

#### Project Run Configurations

1. Right click project, go to properties
2. Go to "Run Configurations"
3. Change "Run As" to "Script (Run in command line)"

[Here is NetBeans doc](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#scriptCommandLine), but it's outdated... however logic is same.

#### Netbeans Console

Since NetBeans 6.9 you can use terminal within NetBeans.

1. Go to Window->Output->Terminal
2. `cd /path/to/your/project/`
3. `php test.php`

Comment: In NetBeans 8.0 Terminal is located in menu: Window->IDE_Tools->Terminal